# ArcGIS Pro published layer not picking correct display field

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, map-service, arcgis-portal

I have published a map service using ArcGIS Pro. It contains 3 group layer and inside each group 10-15 layers. For each layer i have configured the display field in ArcGIS Pro by opening layer properties and selecing the column which i need to be displayed. (This i used to do in ArcGIS Desktop as well). This display field can be checked from ArcGIS Server rest service page.

Now the problem which i am facing is the service which i publish, layers in that are not picking up the correct display field. 
I never faced such problem when i was using ArcGIS Desktop.

Anyone faced a similar issue ?

Update: I have updated ArcGIS Pro to 2.4 and issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've just encountered this issue. ArcGIS Pro (currently at 2.3 version) seems to 'pick' a display field for you when publishing a service and ignores any attribute you set it to. ArcMap (at 10.51) still publishes the value correctly. I can't find a bug report for this particular issue either.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?